# 3 rows layout, with total min-height: 100%

Tags: css, layout

I would like to achieve a 3 rows layout that behaves like this:

Content is displayed in the middle row. With no content, it just has the fixed height header on top of the screen and the fixed hight footer at the bottom. The middle row is empty and fills up the remaining height of the window.

With increasing content, the middle row gets larger. When it reaches the max size, the total layout size increases, so that the user now has to scroll to see the lower content and the footer.

I kind of managed to do that with tables:

http://jsfiddle.net/v73c4L7n/8/   (lot of content)
http://jsfiddle.net/v73c4L7n/9/   (little content)

HTML

```
<table class="main">
    <tr><td>HEADER</td></tr>
    <tr class="middle">
        <td>
            <div class="area">
                <p>Content</p>
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>FOOTER</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.area {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0px auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.main tr:first-child, .main tr:last-child {
    height: 50px;
}
```

The problem is, that it doesn't seem to work in IE9 or IE10. I think, the problem is the `height:100%` of `.area` inside a table cell, that has no explicit height.

So I wondered if there is a better approach to this kind of layout.

Comment: You should not use <table> for layout. Use <div>, there a dozens of tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you given a try to set `.middle` `height` to `100%` too ?

this way, the `.middle` `<tr>` will take as much place wich remains, others `<tr>` will expand according to their content.

http://jsfiddle.net/v73c4L7n/10/ (works in latest browsers .

updated CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.area {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0px auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:1px
}
.main {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.main .middle > td {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
}
.main tr:first-child, .main tr:last-child {
    height: 50px;
}
.main tr:first-child > td {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}
.main tr:last-child > td {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
}
.middle {
    height:100%;
}
```

It worlks too with `display:table` and regular tag elements such as `header`, `main` and `footer`. http://jsfiddle.net/v73c4L7n/13/

`Display:flex;` makes things even easier : http://jsfiddle.net/v73c4L7n/14/

display:table is understood since IE8, flex since IE10 :(

Comment: Thanks! However, your first example and the flex example don't seem to work in IE10? The second solution seems to work nice, but do you have by any change an idea how i can have another element inside `article` that just expands to the current height of the middle area?

Comment: @basilikum you may need to prefix the rules for some browsers (take a look at caniuse.com). for the middle area , nop, unless flex is in action or javascript. To draw columns, you may relay on the faux-column method: http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns

Comment: thanks again. Seems to be the best answer for my initial question. Although I ended up using JavaScript for the task, since no CSS hack fulfilled all my criteria and display:flex doesn't run on IE9, which I still need to support.

Answer (score 1):

Use divs not tables if you can. I would use the calc(expression) to get 100% height minus the sum of the footer and header. Look here in the fiddle. If you delete some of the paragraphs in the content div you will see it moves the footer to the bottom of the page even if theres no content.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v73c4L7n/12/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
    HEADER
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
    <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
    <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
    <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
    <p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p><p>content</p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    FOOTER
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100%;
}

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}   

#header{
    height: 50px; 
    width: 100%;
    background-color:purple;
}

#content {
    background-color:green; 
    min-height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px); /* Firefox */
    min-height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px); /* Chrome, Safari */
    min-height: calc(100% - 100px); /* IE9+ and future browsers */
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#footer {
    height: 50px; 
    width:100%; 
    background-color:purple;
}
```

Comment: hello, if you want to drop the table structure you can still use their peticular layout wich is well adapted here. Else the display flex properties will be even better but less browser will understand it. I'm not found of calc() but it works, my cent

Comment: OK mate. Like how you changed your answer after you saw mine. Glad you found some stuff to criticise still though.

Comment: Hello,  there's never one single way, all solutions have their subtilities. with calc() you basicly freeze the height of the footer here (just like this 10 years old layout http://yidille.free.fr/plux/valign/uploads/pied-coulissant.html ... worked with IE6 ) , display flex or table allows it to shrink/expand according to  content, display:grid is on its way too  ;)